# Is it possible to inline combine swift with any other language?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, clang

I was wondering if it is possible to write inline in swift in any other language?

From the Objective-C times, there was a possibility to write assembly using macros  `__asm__(/*Assembly*/);`

I know that it's possible to use **Objective-C** from **swift**, and in Objective-C you still could wrap anything that was possible before.

I just curious, is there any 'native' support for any other language in the swift compiler?

Comment: Swift 4.2 (ships with Xcode 10) has the ability to *interact* with Python. Interact is very different from "copy-and-paste Python code". As you've found out, there's no way to add assemble to Swift. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0195-dynamic-member-lookup.md